# TypeError: window.plugins is undefined when im using SSLCertificate.Checker

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am facing problem while using SSLCertificate checker plugin.
it is giving window.plugins undefined error.
I have added plugin from git and use it the same way as define in git.
But i dont know where im getting wrong.
Code Snippet!

```
 var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
            document.getElementById("btcon",addEventListener("click",makeconnection));
            function makeconnection(){
        var server = "https://build.phonegap.com";
        var fingerprint = "2B 24 1B E0 D0 8C A6 41 68 C2 BB E3 60 0A DF 55 1A FC A8 45";

      window.plugins.sslCertificateChecker.check(
              successCallback,
              errorCallback,
              server,
              fingerprint);

       function successCallback(message) {
         alert(message);
         alert("Successful");
         // Message is always: CONNECTION_SECURE.
         // Now do something with the trusted server.
       }

       function errorCallback(message) {
         alert(message);
         if (message == "CONNECTION_NOT_SECURE") {
           // There is likely a man in the middle attack going on, be careful!
           alert("Connection is not secured!");
         } else if (message.indexOf("CONNECTION_FAILED") >- 1) {
           // There was no connection (yet). Internet may be down. Try again (a few times) after a little timeout.
           alert("Connection Failed");
         }
       }
        }
        },
```

Git repository link..
        https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: To get out of this error do following steps and you are done!
1) update your android version { "cordova platform update android@6" or any latest version } in my case i used 6.
2) then add plugin and use it.
3) Make sure you have latest version of cordova installed.
4) Some times when you install plugin it will delete all your assets from platform/android/assets/ in this case you have to maintain the backup copy of your project then after installing plugin copy and paste assets files on it (Note! only those file should be copied which has been deleted or not modified.

Comment: Mostly cordova.js and Cordova_Plugin.js is modified so dont replace these files in assets folder.